# R plot except param?

Tags: r, plot, benford.analysis

Please advise what does the `except` parameter does in R `plot` function:

For example:

```
library(benford.analysis)
data(census.2009)

# Check conformity
bfd.cen <- benford(census.2009$pop.2009, number.of.digits = 1) 
plot(bfd.cen, except = c("second order", "summation", "mantissa", "chi squared","abs diff", "ex summation", "Legend"), multiple = F)
```

Maybe there is a good documentation somewhere, I didn't find it yet.

Comment: @G5W here is the full code:
`library(benford.analysis)
data(census.2009)

# Check conformity
bfd.cen <- benford(census.2009$pop.2009, number.of.digits = 1) 
plot(bfd.cen, except = c("second order", "summation", "mantissa", "chi squared","abs diff", "ex summation", "Legend"), multiple = F) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bfd.cen` is an object of type Benford, so you can get the documentation for the plot function that will be used by typing `?plot.Benford`.  There it describes `except` like this:

> **except**
>   it specifies which plots are not going to be plotted.
>   Currently, you can choose from 7 plots: "digits", "second order",
>   "summation", "mantissa", "chi square", "abs diff", "ex summation". If
>   you want to plot all, just put except = "none". The default is not to
>   plot the "mantissa" and "abs diff".

That is there are several different plot types and `except` specifies any that you might NOT plot. Try `plot(bfd.cen,  except="none", multiple=T)` to see all of the plot types.

```
plot(bfd.cen,  except="none", multiple=T)
```

[image: Benford plots]